# less extend multiple classes of same level

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles, less

I wan't to create modular styles for my buttons in Less.
Lets imagine my statement:

```
.btn-base-styles{
    ...
    /* Styles */
    ...
    &:hover,&:focus{ /* Styles */ }
    &.black{ 
        background-color:black; 
        &:hover,&:focus{ /* Styles */ }
    }
    &.red{ 
        background-color:red;
        &:hover,&:focus{ /* Styles */ }
    }
    &.small{ font-size:12px; }
}
```

Now i want to extend my particular button with one or many classes declared before and I tryed this:

```
#my-button{
    &:extend(.btn-base-styles.red.small all);
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. How can I achieve this? My project is a very massive one with many buttons variants and I will need to stay consistent.

**EDIT 2016-11-10**
Please look at comments bellow for a partial solution to this problem.

Comment: There is no such selector as - `.btn-base-styles.red.small`. You only have `.btn-base-styles.red` and `.btn-base-styles.small`.

Comment: I suspect you're expecting `extend` to match selectors in HTML `class` attribute fashion (i.e. where `class = "btn-base-styles red small"` matches styles in `.btn-base-styles`, `.red`, `.small`, `.btn-base-styles.red`, `.btn-base-styles.small` `.btn-base-styles..red.small`etc.), but it's not. A selector in `extend` parameters really means exactly that selector explicitly (in your examlple `.btn-base-styles.red.small` *only*) and not any kind of "a list of selectors to match".

Comment: @seven-phases-max So if I understand you well, I would have needed my to match thoses classes exactly  in my html in such manner `<button class="btn-base-styles red small">example</button>` instead of trying to assign thoses in my less with selectors. Well, how can I achieve this without explicitly need to add thoses classes directly to each buttons in the html, is this possible?

Comment: "how can I achieve this without explicitly need to add thoses classes" - W/o a major refactoring of your CSS (whether you're use an existing framework or create your own)? I'm afraid there's no easy way (speaking of `extend` [here's collection of similar Qs at SO](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462) with more details on why it's actually pretty much useless).

Comment: For your particular example, curiously the shortest Less code that could produce the expected result would be something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/8c5adac99908000db905976ddfc468a4) - but I doubt the bloat of its CSS output makes it usable in a real project (unless you could also try to optimize it with some css-minifier with its *heaviest* aggressive optimizations turned on (`clean-css` probably will be able to)).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thank you for your last answer. Deeply sorry for I cannot upvote, I have yet to gain this privilege. But as for my problem, I have fixed it the way you have suggested.

Comment: (Just in case:) Technically, an extend equivalent (in *this* particular case) of the mixin method above would be `:extend(.btn-base-styles all, .red all, .small all)`, but it's producing even more bloating CSS output (obviously `extend` is much less optimal than mixins when it comes to longer selectors and styles with one or two properties).